# How to return 0 instead of Nan in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, nan

```
let need = (Singleton.shared.getTotalExpense(category: .need) / Singleton.shared.getTotalIncome()) * 100
      needsLabel.text = "" + String(format: "%.f%%", need)
```

If total expenses and total income are both zero I don't want NaN to be returned. How can I make it so if need = Nan, it returns 0

Comment: can you post `getTotalExpense(category: .need)`

Comment: Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Guessing this is your problem: `let amount = (expense.amount as NSString).floatValue`. A `NSString` is not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to conditionally check if you both numerator and denominator are zero, which is one reason it would result in `NaN`, and conditionally assign zero to the result.

```
let expenses = Singleton.shared.getTotalExpense(category: .need)
let income = Singleton.shared.getTotalIncome()

let need = expenses == 0 && income == 0 ? 0.0 : expenses / income * 100
```

You could also check if the result of division is `NaN` (which could be if any of the operands was `NaN`):

```
let ratio = expenses / income * 100
let need = ratio.isNaN ? 0.0 : ratio
```

Be aware that you might also need to handle a scenario where you divide non-zero by zero - this would result in `Inf` - it all depends on your use case:

```
if ratio.isInfinite {
  // do something else, like throw an exception
}
```

Comment: How would I fix the Inf issue?

Comment: You'd need to check if the denominator is zero (or if the result is `ratio.IsInfinite`), but how you handle it depends on your use case. Do you want to set `need` to zero also? Do you want to throw an exception?, etc

Comment: Sure, so throw an exception in this case